# Orthogonal complement to a graph of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Euclidean/Hermitian vector spaces and $f:E\rightarrow F$ a linear map. Let $\mathcal{G}(f)<E\oplus F$ be the graph of $f$.

Assume if it helps that $\{e_i\}_i$ is an orthonormal basis of $E$, so that $\{(e_i,f(e_i)\}_i$ is a basis of $\mathcal{G}(f)$.

Is there a simple way to describe:

1-  A basis of the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{G}(f)$ in $E\oplus F$ (where we put that $E$ and $F$ are orthogonal) ?

2- A basis of any complement fo $\mathcal{G}(f)$?

Thanks!

Comment: For 2. note that $F\le E\oplus F$ is already a complement of $\mathcal G(f)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way indeed.  The orthogonal complement $\mathcal{G}(f)^\perp$ is given by the graph $\mathcal{G}(-f^*)$, where $f^*\colon F\to E$ is the (Hermitian) adjoint of $f\colon E\to F$.  The proof is simply:
$$
\langle (u,f(u)), (-f^*(v),v)\rangle_{E\oplus F} = \langle u,-f^*(v)\rangle_E+\langle f(u),v\rangle_F=0
$$
for all $u\in E$ and all $v\in F$.  So you can just pick any basis of $F$ and write down a basis of $\mathcal{G}(-f^*)$.